# Yii assertTextPresent not working

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit

Here is my environment `Yii 1.1.10`, `PHPUnit 3.6.0`, `Selenium Server 2.20.0`, `PHP 5.2.17`

Every time i use command `$this->assertTextPresent('Foo');` on my Yii application. PHPUnit seem not responding and didn't give feedback. If i removed that assert, PHPunit is working.

How come?

---

Example of no Responding.

I Tried to test phpunit with SiteTest.php (default test example from Yii)

here is the content of SIteTest.php

```
<?php

class SiteTest extends WebTestCase
{
public function testIndex()
{
    $this->open('');
    $this->assertTextPresent('Welcome');
}

public function testContact()
{
    $this->open('?r=site/contact');
    $this->assertTextPresent('Contact Us');
    $this->assertElementPresent('name=ContactForm[name]');

    $this->type('name=ContactForm[name]','tester');
    $this->type('name=ContactForm[email]','tester@example.com');
    $this->type('name=ContactForm[subject]','test subject');
    $this->click("//input[@value='Submit']");
    $this->waitForTextPresent('Body cannot be blank.');
}

public function testLoginLogout()
{
    $this->open('');
    // ensure the user is logged out
    if($this->isTextPresent('Logout'))
        $this->clickAndWait('link=Logout (demo)');

    // test login process, including validation
    $this->clickAndWait('link=Login');
    $this->assertElementPresent('name=LoginForm[username]');
    $this->type('name=LoginForm[username]','demo');
    $this->click("//input[@value='Login']");
    $this->waitForTextPresent('Password cannot be blank.');
    $this->type('name=LoginForm[password]','demo');
    $this->clickAndWait("//input[@value='Login']");
    $this->assertTextNotPresent('Password cannot be blank.');
    $this->assertTextPresent('Logout');

    // test logout process
    $this->assertTextNotPresent('Login');
    $this->clickAndWait('link=Logout (demo)');
    $this->assertTextPresent('Login');
}
}
```

And this is the result

[image]

seems like phpunit not responding anything. and here is the example if i create my own Test unit without assertion or any test so i will get error.

```
<?php

 Class MessageTest extends CTestCase {

 }

 ?>
```

and here the result.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of "PHPUnit seem not responding"?

Comment: @DavidHarkness i edit my question, adding example of PHPunit not responding. :)

Comment: PHPUnit instantiates each test case once per test method and `@dataProvider` before displaying the PHPUnit version. If any of those modules or class call `exit` or cause an error, PHPUnit will die without any output whatsoever. Turn on all error reporting in `php.ini` and set `error_log` to a file you can write to. This should give you some clue as to why it's failing before running tests.

Comment: BTW, your last example is pretty clear: PHPUnit will fail any test without any test methods or assertions.

Comment: @DavidHarkness yes, the second test. is for testing if phpunit is running normally or not. The question is about the first test.

Comment: That still leaves my previous comment. Does your `bootstrap.php` set up your environment correctly, including the include path and any autoloader needed to find classes such as `WebTestCase`?

Comment: @DavidHarkness i now still in progress to turn on all error reporting in my `php.ini` to see why it's die before do anything. Soon will let you know.

Comment: In my opinion, problems may come from this PHPUnit version. PHPUnit version 3.5.15 works much more better than 3.6 (I have found some bugs in this version), so maybe you will try to downgrade PHPUnit?

Comment: @faramka how can i downgrade PHPUnit? using mac and installed it from PEAR terminal.

Comment: http://www.niden.net/2012/01/downgrading-phpunit-from-36-to-35.html

Answer (score 0):

There may be a syntax error somewhere else, try adding

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // or error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
```

to the end of your bootstrap.php